# how to identify which button clicked in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I have two buttons that execute the same function, and that function needs to evaluate go backward or go forward as I show in the following image

[image]

and in the following code I want to evaluate what function next() or prev() to execute depending on which button was touched, this is built in react

> const onFinish = (values)  =>   {

> ```
> if (values.users) {
>   const Operator = values.users.map((item) => ({
>     ruleAttributeName: item.ruleAttributeName,
>
>     isoAttributeId: item.isoAttributeId,
>
>     ruleOperationId: item.ruleOperationId,
>
>     mandatoryValue: item.mandatoryValue,
>   }));
>   setAttributes(Operator);
> }
> if (values.users) {
>   const attributesSave = values.users.map((item) => ({
>     ruleAttributeName: item.ruleAttributeName,
>     isoAttributeEntity: {
>       isoAttributeId: item.isoAttributeId,
>     },
>     ruleOperationEntity: {
>       ruleOperationId: item.ruleOperationId,
>     },
>     mandatoryValue: item.mandatoryValue,
>   }));
>   console.log('mandatory';
>   setAttributesSave(attributesSave);
>   setMandatoryValue();
>   next();
>   prev();
>    };
> ```

and in this form I pass by parameter the function

> ```
> <Form
>   name='dynamic_form_nest_item'
>   onFinish={onFinish}
>   autoComplete='off'
> >
> ```

Comment: put the actual code in your questions not image. so it's easier to copy your code and give the answer based on it

Comment: Assign a unique id to each button. In your `onFinish` function, identify them as `event.target.id`. `even` variable will automatically be passed to it from the button.

Comment: I already modified

Answer (score 7):

You can identify them by assigning unique Id to both button like this

```
<button onClick={onFinish} Id={'1'}>Next</button>
<button onClick={onFinish} Id={'2'}>Next</button>
```

And in you listener check id which button clicked.

```
const onFinish = (event) => {
  Let id = event.target.id;
  if(id=== "1") {
    // Do for one
  } else {
    // For second
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the parameters that you got on that custom buttons and how is it triggering onClick event. But here is the solution for HTML buttons.

You can set a value to the button like this.

```
<button onClick={onFinish} value="next">Next</button>

const onFinish = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault() // this is to prevent the refresh
  
  const { value } = ev.target // equals with const value = ev.target.value
  if(value === "next") {
    next()
  } else {
    prev()
  }
}
```